# Batch apex UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW

Tags: apex, batch

We are facing the problems when running the batch apex getting below error

> First error: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   0061A000012kKuBQAU; first error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain
>   exclusive access to this record or 156 records

Can any one please suggest how to avoid these error?

Comment: Can you please post your code here

Comment: Are there some triggers on accounts that update child opportunities?

Comment: @kurunve..Am trying to checking check box from opportunities level..There are so many triggers are there..But i hope there is no problem from triggers  Thanks